# Where can I find Meta Stack Overflow in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I am searching for **Meta Stack Overflow** in the Stack Exchange app in Android. Where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: You can always add the meta to your favorites and find it that way since it does not appear to show in the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on All Sites; normally, all *main* sites are listed in the next screen but there is an option to show all sites (including metas) or just the meta sites.

[image] [image]

Comment: Yup already tried but `Meta -StackOverflow` is not coming in the list

Comment: Doing the same as you said but still can't see any Meta - StackOverflow

Comment: It should be there - did you tap "all sites" in the drawer (shown in your screenshot), and then select "all sites" in the dropdown (top right, as shown in this answer) ? Can you get to it by clicking "edit" in the drawer ?

Comment: Meta Stackoverflow does not appear in the list of meta sites for some reason.

Comment: @Glorfondel finally it's coming in the list..after 3-4 weeks